# Best way to find the active wireless device

Tags: linux, command-line, wifi

Of course I know the command:
`iwconfig`

which lists devices (and gives info about whether they have a wireless connection). For the purposes of a shell script, I'm really wondering, is there any way to list only the device names that DO have a wireless connection?

Essentially any other iw command (or something similar)...
Specifically looking for solutions besides `iwconfig | grep ...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `ls /sys/class/net | grep w`